# domain name substitution in Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, javascript, darknet

I'm looking for Tor Browser extension that would allow me to define aliaces mapping tor domain names to human readable names.  When encountaring domain names that are present in the mapping, the borwser would instead display the aliace.  That substitution would  occur in places like:

- Mouseover a link at the bottom left
- Domain column of network tab in dev tools
- address bar, obviously

Here are the questons:

1. Is there something like this already available?
2. Is it possible to create? Are there API to control Tor's link mouseover contents, for example?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen it available, but as far as I know the Chromium add-ons API - it's possible *on a chromium level*, Tor Browser is a Firefox, but the generic Firefox is fine for that as well...